# How i can find N combinations using combntns([1:40], 16) and avoid the error message in matlab

Tags: matlab

if I want to get the results of: A = combntns([1:40], 16), Matlab sends the error message:

```
??? Error using ==> vertcat
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

is there a way to get the first 100000 combinations with a jump of 10000: A(1:10000:...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
A=zeros(10000,16);
for t=1:10000
  a=randperm(40);
  A(t,:)=a(1:16);
end
```